# How can can I get theme callback to work for an error page?

Tags: 7, theming

I've created a custom error handler for 404 errors (page not found).

I've set up *Home » Administration » Configuration » System  » Error Pages* for 404 errors to point to `http://example.com/myerrorpage`, and then I have the following in `hook_menu`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['myerrorpage'] = array(
    'title' => 'myerrorpage',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page callback' => 'myerror_page',
    'theme callback' => 'myerror_theme',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

When I enter a non-existing path (e.g. `http://example.com/bogus`) the *page callback* is invoked as expected.

However, the *theme callback* is not.

To get the  *theme callback* to fire, I need to enter the following path: `http://example.com/myerrorpage`.

I do not understand why the *theme callback* does not fire at the same time as the *page callback*.

Is there any way to get the *theme callback* (or `hook_custom_theme()`) to fire when a non-existing path is given?

Comment: Looks like a bug in core for me. I would expect it to work just like aliases do.

Comment: At first glance this actually does look like a bug (or at least an undocumented limitation) - `menu_get_custom_theme()` is called earlier in the bootstrap then `drupal_deliver_html_page()`, so overriding the menu item to the 404 page in that second function can have no effect on the current theme callback

Comment: As a nasty hack you could provide your own delivery callback function and `unset($_GLOBALS['theme']); drupal_theme_initialize();` between the calls to `menu_set_active_item()` and `menu_execute_active_handler()`. Not pretty, but it should work

Answer (score 0):

In [`menu_get_custom_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_custom_theme/7), you can see that *theme callback* on menu router would not be called if the menu router doesn't exist. But you can achieve that with `hook_custom_theme()`.

I'll go like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_custom_theme().
 */
function MYMODULE_custom_theme() {
  $router_item = menu_get_item();
  if (empty($router_item)) {
    return 'THEME_NAME';
  }
}
```